# Windows Find Regex - findstr LookBehind

Tags: windows, powershell, regex, findstr

I have this string:

```
DisplayName    REG_SZ    Paquete de controladores de Windows - Intel Corporation (iaStorA) HDC  (07/22/2015 14.5.2.1088)
```

Which I have taken from:

`Reg Query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s /v DisplayName`

What I want is the exact name of the product: `Paquete de controladores de Windows - Intel Corporation (iaStorA) HDC  (07/22/2015 14.5.2.1`

I am trying this:

```
PS> Reg Query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s /v DisplayName | select -First 3 | findstr.exe /i /r /c:"(?<=REG_SZ\s*).*"
```

But it's not like a `grep -Po` in Linux and can't figure it out.

Comment: You are mixing powershell and batch file commands. See https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html for findstr regexp definitions.

Answer (score 0):

### So you have this string. . .

```
DisplayName    REG_SZ    Paquete de controladores de Windows - Intel Corporation (iaStorA) HDC  (07/22/2015 14.5.2.1088)
```

### You need to end with this string. . .

```
Paquete de controladores de Windows - Intel Corporation (iaStorA) HDC  (07/22/2015 14.5.2.1)
```

### Consider. . .

*Consider using the [Get-ItemProperty](https://ss64.com/ps/get-itemproperty.html) with applicable options and parameters to get registry information instead of **Reg Query**.*

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

---

### Other PowerShell Method

Use the [Replace()](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html) and [Trim()](https://ss64.com/ps/trim.html) functions to parse out and then clean up the string you need instead.

> **Powershell [Replace()](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html) and [Trim()](https://ss64.com/ps/trim.html) function example**
>
> ```
> $s = "DisplayName    REG_SZ    Paquete de controladores de Windows - Intel Corporation (iaStorA) HDC  (07/22/2015 14.5.2.1088)"
> $s = $s.replace('DisplayName    REG_SZ', '').Trim()
> $s
> ```

### My Test Verification

[image]

---

### Further Resources

- [Replace()](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html)
- [Trim()](https://ss64.com/ps/trim.html)
- [Get-ItemProperty](https://ss64.com/ps/get-itemproperty.html)